# Difference between read_stream and user_posts permissions in v2.2

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are trying to track how well posts generated from our platform are doing in terms of like and comment count. We understand that read_stream isn't going to be an option, but we noticed there's a user_posts permission which is supposed to let us get posts that the user posted or is tagged in.

While testing it seems sort of spotty when the likes/comments are returned with this other permission. Does anyone know what the differences between these 2 permissions are and what data we should be able to get?

Answer (score 3):

I think this should be clear from the docs. Or, I don't understand your question:

`user_posts` (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-user_posts)

> Provides access to the posts on a person's Timeline. Includes their own posts, posts they are tagged in, and posts other people make on their Timeline.

`read_stream` (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-read_stream)

> Provides access to read the posts in a person's News Feed, or the posts on their Profile.

Comment: read_stream I see returning likes/comments always, user_posts I see them only coming sometimes. I'm unsure when they should be there vs. not

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why user_posts is mentioned in the user/feed API docs, but not in the /{post id} docs. I seem to have access to both.

Comment: Hmm, if you have examples of non-returning likes/comments, I'd suggest you open a Bug with Facebook and let them verify this behavior.

Comment: Reason why it is not mentioned in the post object docs yet might be that they only introduced `user_posts` a few days ago. And the reason you are not getting likes and shares might be that the users who liked or shared the post have not also granted your app that level of read access to _their_ data.

Comment: I am trying to fetch user_posts, but it requires a permission! To get the permission I need to use the wizard which is asking for the implementation. I do not understand how can I implement something without permission, seems like I am doing something wrong. Please help me out

Comment: Hello is there any update to this topic? I am facing similar problem as of @VipinBardia